# Angular material right way to open next dialog with $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

In my code i show `$mdDialog` dialog for user:

```
$mdDialog.show({
   controller: 'loadingDialogCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'tmpl/loadingDialog.tmpl.html'
});
```

Then after ajax response i want to close it and show error dialog:

```
error: function (err) {               
  $mdDialog.hide();
  $mdDialog.alert()
           .title('Error')
           .textContent(err)
           .ariaLabel('Alert command error')
           .ok('Ok');
  }
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

See following code.
After closing the mdDialog, there are 2 block same as ajax call(success and error)
So call your error prompt(dialog) in one of them.

```
$mdDialog.show({
   controller: 'loadingDialogCtrl',
   templateUrl: 'tmpl/loadingDialog.tmpl.html'
}).then(function(){
   //success block
   //this block will get called when when you do $mdDialog.hide();
   //in your loadingDialogCtrl
   //then the below dialog will open
   $mdDialog.alert()
      .title('Error')
      .textContent(err)
      .ariaLabel('Alert command error')
      .ok('Ok');
}, function(){
   //error block
});
```

This code is in main controller, hide/close the first dialog and do things in main controller.

Comment: how to open one by one ?

Comment: You are able to open first right? when you close it, open the other in the response are of first as shown in my answer

Comment: Yes, yours works. But i need to show dialog for block ui without buttons.

Comment: This would be much more understandable if you placed your question in a working jsfiddle.

Comment: I want to have behavior like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5qCm9/43/   but this is example on bootstrap.

Comment: Did you even tried my answer, because that's exactly what I'm doing except it is not closing on timeout you need to close the first dialog.

Comment: Somehow I am not able to set a jsfiddle, you can check this link https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog